# Restart/Refresh Dock - killall Dock - cache

Tags: cocoa, macos, dock

I've made an app which changes the OSX Trash icon. However after it has replaced the icon .png files in .../CoreServices/Dock.app/Resources it will not show the new icon before the Trash has changed state (fx. empty -> full or full -> empty). I've tried making the change appear by using killall Dock, killall Finder but not working.. I've also read about deleting a dock cache file in Library/Caches/com.apple.dock... But i can't seem to find this file?

Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually ended up using the bash command `find . -name com.apple.dock.iconcache`. Then I deleted all of the matches. It works perfectly!

Comment: Can you pleae explain how to do this more. I have a .app file on my desktop, i went inside it to contents/resources/appicon.icns and replaced it with another icon and renamed appicon.icns. I then went to Finder and typed in `find "/Users/noi/Desktop/noits.app" -name com.apple.dock.iconcache` it threw no errors, but no lines came back :(

Answer (score 0):

there are two states for  trash. the empty trash and the something in it trash icon....are u sure u have changed BOTH of them in the plist in your program... !! if u change both of them separately . i m sure it will work...

oh yes...and the plist ur looking for is in the folder /Users/(your username)/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock..... hope this helps

Comment: oh yes...and the plist ur looking for is in the folder /Users/(your username)/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock..... hope this helps